# Multiple validation under single input type

Tags: regex, html, validation, input

I am working on a project. I have used `[a-zA-Z]+` for only alphabetic input. I want to restrict a user to start with only (BS- or MSC-) and then input anything
Below is the input type:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Degree Name Example BS-IT" name="degree" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" title="Example BS-IT">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `BS-` and `MSC-` criteria into the regular expression. Such as:

```
(BS-|MSC-)[-a-zA-Z]+
```